# How to re-write Guice Interface DI Injector.getInjector().getInstance(Interface.class) on Spring or EE

Tags: java, guice

Guice is avaliable for getting instance of Interface.class,
But how we can get the same thing for **Interface** in Java EE or Spring?

```
TestVar testVar = Injector.getInjector().getInstance(Interface.class)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using spring the IoC container is the ApplicationContext. You can directly request it like this.

```java
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
Interface myService = ctx.getBean(Interface.class);
```

Or you can inject it to your component.

Keep in mind this is a bad practice. You should never request the container directly. You should let it resolve dependencies for you.

Comment: JEY, thank you for your answer. I know about that usage. But my case is about injecting Interface. Guice can getInstance(Interface), but I'm not sure about Spring or EE.

Comment: You can do ctx.getBean(Interface.class) that doesn't change anything